# Merge Unique Values Into One Row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to condense rows for each user ID into one row with only unique Product ID's as well as exclude any where the count of the unique products is >2. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

```
+--------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
| UserID       | ProductID1  | CoverageLevel1  |  ProductID2 | CoverageLevel2  |
+--------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
|     1        | 90001439952 |        C        | 90001439952 |       C         |
|     1        | 90001439952 |        C        | 90026439964 |       A         |
|     2        | 90145434879 |        A        | 90017434947 |       D         |
|     2        | 90145434879 |        A        | 90017434947 |       B         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Since UserID=2 has unique values (90145434879 & A, 90017434947 & D, 90017434947 & B) then all of the records for that ID would be excluded.

```
+--------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
| UserID       | ProductID1  | CoverageLevel1  |  ProductID2 | CoverageLevel2  |
+--------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
|     1        | 90001439952 |        C        | 90026439964 |       A         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: UserID = 1 also have 3 unique values (90001439952 | C, 90003439972 | C, 90026439964 | A). So, why shouldn't this user also  excluded ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze Sorry that was an error and I've edited it out. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Also, why you expect second row (in your example) for UserID = 1  and why not first row ? What is logic here?

Comment: @OtoShavadze For this example, its best to treat it as if it is being pulled straight from the DB. The logic itself is very hard to explain, it is transactional data and needs a lot of background to understand. Ive changed the field names and values because the data is protected